# java.lang.nullpointerException in spinners

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I'm a beginner to android development.I'm trying to make a converter app which converts meter to cm.But in onClick method its not getting the selected item from spinner.except that the app stops.

MainActivity.java

```
package com.example.spinnertext;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    Spinner sp;
    EditText et;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        sp=(Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
        ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter= ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this, R.array.items, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
        sp.setAdapter(adapter);
        sp.setOnItemSelectedListener(new CustomListener());
        Button b=(Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        b.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                EditText et=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
                sp=(Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
                Double d = null,s=Double.valueOf(et.getText().toString());
                if(arg0.getId()==R.id.spinner1)
                {
                    Log.d("TEST", "From Main");
                    if(sp.getSelectedItemPosition()==0)
                    {
                        d=s*100;
                        Log.d("TEST", "Meter From Main");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Log.d("TEST", "Cm From Main");
                        d=s;
                    }
                }
                Toast.makeText(arg0.getContext(), d.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
    }


}
```

CustomListener.java

```
package com.example.spinnertext;

import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener;

public class CustomListener implements OnItemSelectedListener {

    @Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,
            long arg3) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Log.d("TEST", arg0.getSelectedItem().toString()+"selected");

    }

    @Override
    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

}
```

The layout file:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="31dp"
        android:ems="10" />

    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/spinner1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/editText1"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/editText1"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/editText1" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_below="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_marginTop="42dp"
        android:textSize="25sp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/editText1"
        android:layout_below="@+id/editText1"
        android:layout_marginTop="47dp"
        android:text="Button" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

the LogCat shows Following Error:

```
03-24 13:22:05.357: D/libEGL(1505): loaded /system/lib/egl/libEGL_genymotion.so
03-24 13:22:05.361: D/(1505): HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0xb89c08e8, tid 1505
03-24 13:22:05.385: D/libEGL(1505): loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv1_CM_genymotion.so
03-24 13:22:05.385: D/libEGL(1505): loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv2_genymotion.so
03-24 13:22:05.465: W/EGL_genymotion(1505): eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
03-24 13:22:05.465: E/OpenGLRenderer(1505): Getting MAX_TEXTURE_SIZE from GradienCache
03-24 13:22:05.497: E/OpenGLRenderer(1505): Getting MAX_TEXTURE_SIZE from Caches::initConstraints()
03-24 13:22:05.497: D/OpenGLRenderer(1505): Enabling debug mode 0
03-24 13:22:05.525: D/TEST(1505): Meterselected
03-24 13:22:10.481: D/AndroidRuntime(1505): Shutting down VM
03-24 13:22:10.485: W/dalvikvm(1505): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0xa4bd5648)
03-24 13:22:10.489: E/AndroidRuntime(1505): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-24 13:22:10.489: E/AndroidRuntime(1505): java.lang.NullPointerException
03-24 13:22:10.489: E/AndroidRuntime(1505):     at com.example.spinnertext.MainActivity$1.onClick(MainActivity.java:50)
03-24 13:22:10.489: E/AndroidRuntime(1505):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4240)
03-24 13:22:10.489: E/AndroidRuntime(1505):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17721)
03-24 13:22:10.489: E/AndroidRuntime(1505):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:730)
03-24 13:22:10.489: E/AndroidRuntime(1505):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
03-24 13:22:10.489: E/AndroidRuntime(1505):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
03-24 13:22:10.489: E/AndroidRuntime(1505):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
03-24 13:22:10.489: E/AndroidRuntime(1505):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-24 13:22:10.489: E/AndroidRuntime(1505):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
03-24 13:22:10.489: E/AndroidRuntime(1505):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
03-24 13:22:10.489: E/AndroidRuntime(1505):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
03-24 13:22:10.489: E/AndroidRuntime(1505):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

The LogCat show message from the CustomListener class but OnClick Methods Logs are not shown.

Comment: what is there at MainActivity.java:50 ?

Comment: Keep Edittext initialization outside `onClick()` @Josef

Comment: My money is on the d.toString() call, d will most likely be null at that point, I mean there is no chance arg0.getId()==R.id.spinner1 isd actually true ...

Comment: Caused by java.lang.NullPointerException, check Line 50 at MainActivity.java.

Comment: Please can you tell what line 50 is. Also I advice to make a breakpoint at line 50 and use debugger to check what value of variable is null

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`arg0.getId()==R.id.spinner1` will always return `false`, because `arg0` is a reference to your button. This means your `d` reference is never initialized (you only do it inside your `if` clause), hence calling `d.toString()` causes the NullPointerException.

Answer (score 0):

You have a null pointer exception in your toast.

```
Toast.makeText(arg0.getContext(), d.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

Probably arg0==null or d==null.

Check this two values pls

Comment: How could `arg0` be `null`?

Comment: He can't. This are the two options to have null pointer exception but probably the problem is in the variable "d". You initialize it with null and probably never change is value.

Comment: `arg0` is the `View` that intercepted the `onClick()`

Answer (score 0):

Take out:

```
         et=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
         sp=(Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
```

from `onClick` to `onCreate()` and declare them as final global variables:

```
         private final EditText et;
         private final Sinner sp;
```

then you can use them in `onClick()`

Hope this help!

Comment: no where near about the actual cause of the problem. we should read  the problem at the first position.

Comment: Although this is a better coding practice, it would not solve the problem of the NullPointerException, IMO...